# How to model filtering to list various columns based on REST

Tags: rest

How to model filtering of various users to list different columns based on REST.

```
/users/all will show all columns in CSV format (e.g. val1, val2, val3, val4)
/users/?? will show few columns in CSV format (e.g. val1, val2, val3)
/users/?? will show few columns in CSV format (e.g. val1, val2)
/users/?? will show few columns in CSV format (e.g. val1)
```

How should I model a single REST endpoint to support various filtering options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/users/?columns="val1,val2,val3,val4"
/users/?columns="val1,val2,val3"
/users/?columns="val1,val2"
/users/?columns="val1"
```

(you have to send the proper accept header to get CSV)

another option to use a [prefer header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240)

Comment: Instead of columns shown as a query parameter, can I use a different pattern with the URL itself? What other options are available.

Comment: @Rpj There is no standard way how to define these URI templates. According to the URI standard the path part must contain the hierarchical part of the URI and the query part must contain the non-hierarchical part of the URI. That's all. In the current case you map reduce an item collection to fewer fields, so the field names could be in the path part as well, but I think it is better this way. It does not matter from the perspective of the REST client, it will use the link you give to it, and the attached metadata, e.g. link relation.